# Can I make parallel requests with PyQt5's QThread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, pyqt5, qthread

I have a code which makes my requests faster. Now, I need to run similar code in PyQt5 without blocking main program. Can QThread solve that problem?

This is the code before I wrote with ThreadPoolExecutor :

```py
    def analyze(self):
        if not os.path.exists('input.avi'):
            return
        self.results = []
        with PoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
            for _ in executor.map(self.post, self.images):
                pass

        if len(self.results) > 0:
            self.results.sort()

        print(self.results)

    def post(self, imageWithID):
        if len(self.images) == 0:
            return

        if self.subscription_key is None or self.subscription_key == '':
            return

        self.results = []
        errors = 0
        id, image = imageWithID[0], imageWithID[1]
        image2 = image.copy()
        bytedata = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image2)[1].tostring()

        while errors < 3:
            response = requests.post(self.face_api_url,
                                     params=self.params,
                                     headers=self.headers,
                                     data=bytedata).json()
            if 'error' in response:
                errors += 1
                if response['error']['code'] == '429':
                    print(tup[0], 'sleeping...')
                    time.sleep(
                        int(response['error']['message'].split(' ')[-2]))
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            else:
                break
        self.results.append((id, image, response))
```

Is it possible to do that with QThread(I mean with multi threaded QThread, not single for increasing speed), so it'll not freeze main program body I think.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem myself. Here is my complete QThread code.

```py
class analyzingThread(QThread):
    i = 0
    pause = False
    sync = PyQt5.QtCore.QMutex()
    pauseCond = PyQt5.QtCore.QWaitCondition()
    images = []
    results = []
    subscription_key = 'MY_SUPER_SECRET_AZURE_API_KEY'
    face_api_url = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
               'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key
               }
    params = {
        'returnFaceId': 'false',
        'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
        'returnFaceAttributes': 'emotion'}

    def resume(self):
        self.sync.lock()
        self.pause = False
        self.sync.unlock()
        self.pauseCond.wakeAll()

    def pausem(self):
        self.sync.lock()
        self.pause = True
        self.sync.unlock()

    def post(self, imageWithId):
        errors = 0
        id, img = imageWithId[0], imageWithId[1]
        bytedata = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()
        while errors < 3:
            response = requests.post(self.face_api_url,
                                     params=self.params,
                                     headers=self.headers,
                                     data=bytedata).json()
            if 'error' in response:
                errors += 1
                if response['error']['code'] == '429':
                    print(imageWithId[0], 'sleeping...')
                    time.sleep(
                        int(response['error']['message'].split(' ')[-2]))
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            else:
                break
        self.results.append((id, img, response))

    def concrrPost(self):
        if len(self.images) == 0:
            print('no images')
            return
        with PoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
            for _ in executor.map(self.post, self.images):
                pass

        self.results.sort()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.sync.lock()
            if self.pause:
                self.pauseCond.wait(self.sync)
            self.sync.unlock()
            self.concrrPost()
            print('-DONE-')
            # print(self.results)
            self.pausem()
```

than I connected pausem and resume methods with qpushbuttons :)